# What does x = x(:) mean in matlab, where x is a vector?

Tags: matlab

This is a hard question to google.  I am new to Matlab and have seen the following statement, but I can't see how it does anything.  What doe x = x(:) do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`:` is the [**colon operator**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html).  In this context, it reshapes `x` to a one-dimensional column vector.

So this code:

```
x = [ 1 3
      2 4 ];

x = x(:);

disp(x)
```

results in:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Do you know if it just does a reshape (so will copy on write) or forces a copy at that point (even if x is already a column)?

Comment: @robince: Good question.  I'd like to think that `x(:)` is exactly equivalent to `reshape(x, [], 1)`.  But I don't know for sure (I'm not sure this is documented anywhere).  I suppose one could try to figure it out via profiling.

Comment: Yes I checked and seems to have normal copy on write semantis (with 2011b). I don't know why I had the idea it forced a copy - perhaps it did some time in the past.

Answer (score 2):

x(:) transforms the array to a column vector.

[More about the colon operator](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/10/all-about-the-colon-operator/#8)

Comment: and it's actually not that hard to [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=matlab+colon+operator+vector).

Answer (score 2):

This syntax is generally used to ensure that `x` is a column vector:

```
x = x(:)
```

Similarly, this line ensures that `x` is a row vector

```
x = x(:)'
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, x(:) converts x into a vector, a column vector specifically. The point is that it makes your code robust to the user supplying a row vector my accident. For example,

```
x = 1:5;
```

has created a ROW vector. Some operations will require a column vector. Since x(:) does nothing to a vector that is already a column vector, this is a way of writing robust, stable code.

Of course, if x was a 3x4 matrix, it will still convert x into a column vector of length 12, so the best code needs to test for things like that, if it is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`x(:)` reshapes your matrix.

Thereby, if your matrix is

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
8 9 10
```

calling `x=x(:)` sets `x` to

```
1
5
8 
2
6
9
3
7
10
```

Answer (score 1):

If x is a matrix, like the following: a 3*3 matrix,

```
    x=[1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9];
    x=x(:);
```

The statement x=x(:) lists the matrix as a column vector. 
The output would be

```
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8    
    9
```

The same is what is obtained when x is a row vector.

so in general, x(:) lists the elements of x as column vector.

Answer (score 1):

This operator tells matlab to try to convert the data type also.

For example:

Both data types set as disparate types:

```
>> foo = uint8(0);

>> bar = double(0);
```

Check data types with "whos" command:

```
>> whos foo bar
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  bar       1x1                 8  double              
  foo       1x1                 1  uint8
```

Assign the uint8 into the double with the (:) operator:

```
>> bar(:) = foo;
```

and it remains a double

```
>> whos foo bar
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  bar       1x1                 8  double              
  foo       1x1                 1  uint8
```

assign the double with a unit8 without the (:) operator :

```
>> bar = foo;
```

and it changes to a uint8 data type:

```
>> whos foo bar
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  bar       1x1                 8  uint8      
  foo       1x1                 1  uint8
```